# Steam Counter Strike 1.6 Linux beta with optimus (optirun/primusrun)

Tags: games, nvidia-optimus, steam

I was able to run Sam 3 on nvidia card before. Now they added CS 1.6 but they changed paths. I modified the original command I was using for sam3 but it doesnt work.

```
cd ~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/ && 
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32 && 
    primusrun ./hl_linux -game cstrike -console -dev -numericping -noipx
```

Its giving me this error:

**Error:libsteam_api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not load hw.so.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours I found it. You need to add game root path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
cd ~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/ &&
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32:~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/ &&
primusrun ./hl_linux -game cstrike -console -dev -numericping -noipx
```

Also you need to be running Steam before you run the game.

Plus if you want to disable vertical sync you need to run

```
export vblank_mode=0
```

before running the game. So this is full bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export vblank_mode=0
cd ~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/ && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32:~/.steam/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/ && primusrun ./hl_linux -game cstrike -nosync
```

Comment: Is there a way to do with the `steam steam://rungameid/10` command? I've tried but cannot figure out where to modify steam:// protocol.

Comment: Never tried that , but this is pretty outdated. Im using nvidia-prime now. It still cant do it on the fly, you need to restart ubuntu, but it should work out of the box.